# How to execute codes inside a macro?

Tags: tables, macros

I use Michael Wichura's old Table macros (see http://www.pctex.com/addons.html) in several places, and I need to access them from within another macro. The problem (I think) is that some of the characters that are used in the Table macros are not passed on correctly. Let me illustrate with some codes.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

% These three lines read the macros
\input{nine}
\input{eight}
\input{Table}

\begin{document}

This is a table: % The following few lines use the Table macros
 $$
 \BeginTable
  \BeginFormat
  | lw8 | rw4 | rw4 |
  \EndFormat
  " Line 1  " 1.23 " 4.56 "\\
  " Line 2  " 7.89 " 0.12 "\\
 \EndTable
 $$

\def\QuestionSolution{Q} % This identifies whether I want a question or solution

\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\QuestionSolution}{S}{%
This is the question}{%
This is the solution with the same table:
 $$
 \BeginTable
  \BeginFormat
  | lw20 | rw4 | rw4 |
  \EndFormat
  " Line 1  " 1.23 " 4.56 "\\
  " Line 2  " 7.89 " 0.12 "\\
 \EndTable
$$}

\end{document}
```

The output I get from this code looks like this:

[image]

The first table is fine but, clearly, there is a problem when the table macros are invoked from within the \ifstrequal macro. In fact, the same problem occurs when I call the table from *any* macro.

Of course, I know that I could reconstruct all of these tables using more standard LaTeX codes. The problem is that I have about 200 such (full-page) tables to rewrite in a fairly short interval of time.

Is there an easier way to fix this problem?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: See [Why is `\[` …`\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Comment: Actually @Werner, in this case I think `$$` is preferable because it is being used as a quick way to center the table (something that I have seen many plain tex users do)

Comment: @Aditya Well, in that case, `\centerline` is the correct option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\scantokens` and a command that makes the input less awkward and the processing more flexible.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\QS}[2]{%
  \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\QuestionSolution}{S}{#1}{\scantokens{#2}}%
}

% These three lines read the macros
\input{nine}
\input{eight}
\input{Table}

\begin{document}

This is a table: % The following few lines use the Table macros
 $$
 \BeginTable
  \BeginFormat
  | lw8 | rw4 | rw4 |
  \EndFormat
  " Line 1  " 1.23 " 4.56 "\\
  " Line 2  " 7.89 " 0.12 "\\
 \EndTable
 $$

\def\QuestionSolution{Q} % This identifies whether I want a question or solution

\QS{This is the question}{%
This is the solution with the same table:
 $$
 \BeginTable
  \BeginFormat
  | lw8 | rw4 | rw4 |
  \EndFormat
  " Line 1  " 1.23 " 4.56 "\\
  " Line 2  " 7.89 " 0.12 "\\
 \EndTable
$$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative without `\scantokens`, but less flexible, is

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\QS}{%
  \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\QuestionSolution}{S}{\@firstoftwo}{\@gobble}%
}
\makeatother
```

The second argument is actually read as such only in the true case, when it's discarded. In the "false" case, the first argument is discarded by `\@gobble` and the table is processed (inside a group, but it should make no difference).

Answer (score 5):

When you use a macro like `\something{<x>}{<y>}{<z>}`, LaTeX reads all of the arguments `<x>`, `<y>` and `<z>` before processing things inside `\something`. And you're right, there are category codes that are changed as part of [PiCTeX's Table macros](http://www.pctex.com/kb/47.html) that cannot happen after the arguments have been read. As such, you need a different approach to handling this, avoiding the use of a macro conditional.

Below I've used the pdfTeX primitive `\pdfstrcmp{<one>}{<two>}` which returns a value of `0` if `<one>` is equal to `<two>`. You can then use a regular `\ifnum<pdfstroutput>=0 <T>\else <F>\fi` construct to condition on the equality:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% These three lines read the macros
\input{pictable/nine}
\input{pictable/eight}
\input{pictable/Table}

\begin{document}

This is a table: % The following few lines use the Table macros
\[
  \BeginTable
    \BeginFormat
      | lw8 | rw4 | rw4 |
    \EndFormat
    " Line 1  " 1.23 " 4.56 "\\
    " Line 2  " 7.89 " 0.12 "\\
  \EndTable
\]

\def\QuestionSolution{Q} % This identifies whether I want a question or solution

\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\QuestionSolution}{S}=0%
  This is the question
\else%
  This is the solution with the same table:
 \[
   \BeginTable
    \BeginFormat
    | lw20 | rw4 | rw4 |
    \EndFormat
    " Line 1  " 1.23 " 4.56 "\\
    " Line 2  " 7.89 " 0.12 "\\
   \EndTable
 \]
\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Werner. Your explanation and solution make complete sense. Also, you have just saved me about two weeks of (table-rewriting) work.

Comment: perhaps the percent character after `0` in the `\ifnum` test should be removed; it doesn't matter here but with `0%` TeX is going to expand what comes next to finish finding a number. Or do `\if\pdfstrcmp{\QuestionSolution}{S}0%`: in case of `\if-10%` or `\if10%` TeX will take the false branch and the true branch for `\if00%`. In that case the `%`is necessary to avoid adding a spurious space.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another method which does not use `\scantokens`, and it does not have  group braces to be (perhaps, in some cases) removed. It does not use `\ifstrequal` either, only plain `\if`.

(to tell the truth the code here is not "inside a macro" at all)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

%  \usepackage{etoolbox}  % not needed in this approach


\newcommand*{\QS}{\if\QuestionSolution S\expandafter\zaptoS\fi }

\newcommand{\bS}{}      % checking if already defined
% \S is \textsection so I chose \bS (begin S)

\long\def\bS #1\eS{}

\newcommand{\zaptoS}{} %checking if already defined
\long\def\zaptoS #1\bS{}

\newcommand*{\eS}{}   % (end S)


% These three lines read the macros
\input{pictable/base/nine}
\input{pictable/base/eight}
\input{pictable/base/Table}

\begin{document}

This is a table: % The following few lines use the Table macros
 $$
 \BeginTable
  \BeginFormat
  | lw8 | rw4 | rw4 |
  \EndFormat
  " Line 1  " 1.23 " 4.56 "\\
  " Line 2  " 7.89 " 0.12 "\\
 \EndTable
 $$

\def\QuestionSolution{Q} % I want a question

\QS
This is the question
\bS 
This is the solution with the same table:
 $$
 \BeginTable
  \BeginFormat
  | lw8 | rw4 | rw4 |
  \EndFormat
  " Line 1  " 1.23 " 4.56 "\\
  " Line 2  " 7.89 " 0.12 "\\
 \EndTable
$$
\eS

\def\QuestionSolution{S} % I now want here a solution

\QS % question from here to \bS
This is the question
\bS  % solution from here to \eS
This is the solution with the same table:
 $$
 \BeginTable
  \BeginFormat
  | lw8 | rw4 | rw4 |
  \EndFormat
  " Line 1  " 1.23 " 4.56 "\\
  " Line 2  " 7.89 " 0.12 "\\
 \EndTable
$$
\eS

\end{document}
```

[image: codes]

Comment: I propose this answer because it allows inside the questions/solutions to use `\if..\else..\fi` constructs with no surprises, as there is no apparent conditional to TeX apart from the one processed in one go when `\QS` is executed.

Comment: I guess the more common situation is when one wants to display or not display the solutions (the questions being always printed). Then the mark-up needed would be only the `\bS...\eS`. One would have a switch `\ifsolutions` and define `\def\bS{\ifsolutions\else\expandafter\zaptoeS\fi}`, with `\long\def\zaptoeS #1\eS {}` and `\def\eS {}`. This way inside the solution code, arbitrary TeX code can be used with no possible surprise from TeX scanning conditional branches, compared to doing `\ifsolutions <solution code>\fi`.

Comment: Makes me think that the `LaTeX` mark-up `\begin{solution}...\end{solution}` does not make it easy to define the `solution` environment to annihilate conditionally its contents, seems this is exactly the job of package [comment](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/comment).